# Querying the Column Name from another Oracle User

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Okay this is my case. I need to query the Column name of a table from another Oracle Database User. It is with the same schema and same database connections with my username.

This is my query:

```
Select COLUMN_NAME 
from user_tab_columns 
where table_name='CY_3TRAVELTRAX' AND User = 'PUBLISH_PNL_AFPI_2013';
```

But I always got a zero result where in reality that User has many table and columns. Any help?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `user_*` views only contain data for the current user.

Comment: I suggest you remember to search before asking. The first hit on google when you type your title as-is is the above question.

Answer (score 3):

For most `user_` data dictionary views there are also `all_` (and `dba_`) views.

An excerpt from the documentation (at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_1001.htm#i1572007 ) describes it best:

> Many data dictionary tables have three corresponding views:
>
> - An ALL_ view displays all the information accessible to the current
>     user, including information from the current user's schema as well as
>     information from objects in other schemas, if the current user has
>     access to those objects by way of grants of privileges or roles.
> - A DBA_ view displays all relevant information in the entire
>     database. DBA_ views are intended only for administrators. They can be
>     accessed only by users with the SELECT ANY TABLE privilege. This
>     privilege is assigned to the DBA role when the system is initially
>     installed.
> - A USER_ view displays all the information from the schema of the
>     current user. No special privileges are required to query these views.

So you should use:

```
Select COLUMN_NAME
from all_tab_columns
where table_name='CY_3TRAVELTRAX'
AND owner = 'PUBLISH_PNL_AFPI_2013';
```

NB: The column to use is called `OWNER` and not `USER`! The latter is a function that returns the current user (and every DBA gets bitten by this at least once in their career).